# Change cell format (Length?) in Java Poi (Excel)

Tags: java, excel, format, apache-poi, cell

I have been searching for a way to do this but only found a few methods to resize columns, and wasn´t enough.

It´s simple:

When I´m writting into an excel file, I get to a point where numbers get higher than 10.000.000, and the format changes, example:

> row 11: 9.800.000
>
> row 12: 9.900.000
>
> row 13: 1.0E7
>
> row 14: 1.01E7

How can I prevent this from happening? I need the whole number, as I later access this information again from my code.

(I can´t edit excel manually, as I create it dinamically, I guess (and hope) there is a variable in some Java POI class that I can assign a value for this to change?)

Thank you all.

Comment: What cell format have you got applied to the cell? And if it isn't already one with more digits requested than that, what happens if you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to just convert the value when you extract it from the excel file.

```
BigDecimal bigNumber = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue());
//Use bigNumber when doing the calculations
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a cell formatting case, by default Excel use exponential format for numbers below a certain value, for the 2013 version it's below 1E10. And for older versions I guess it's arround 1E7.

To solve this you need to format the cell in your Java code before creating the xls file, using HSSFCellStyle, check the following code:

```
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#"));

Double d = 10000000000.0;
thecell.setCellValue(d);
thecell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
thecell.setCellStyle(style);
```

You may also need to re-size the column the fit the number by adding

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

Here's an output exemple with the cell formatting (A1) and without it (B1):

[image: exemple with the cell formatting]

Dont forget to import the necessary classes.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, you have to set [DataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html) as `"#.000"`:

```
DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#.000"));
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Where:

> 0 - Digit placeholder. For example, if you type 8.9 and you want it to display as 8.90, then use the format #.00
>
> # - Digit placeholder. Follows the same rules as the 0 symbol except Excel does not display extra zeros when the number you type has fewer digits on either side of the decimal than there are # symbols in the format. For example, if the custom format is #.## and you type 8.9 in the cell, the number 8.9 is displayed.

More excel formats: [How to control and understand settings in the Format Cells dialog box in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/264372)